# Initialize "empty" directory

Tags: git, gitignore

File/Directory Structure:

```
main/home/script.py
main/home/a/.init
main/home/b/.init
```

I want to setup my `gitignore` to exclude everything in the home directory but to include specific file types.

What i tried:

```
home/*      #exclude everything in the home directory and subdirectories
!home/*.py  #include python files immediately in the home directory
!**.init    #include .init files in all directories and subdirectories.
```

The problem, i can't seem to make sure `.init` files are included. The purpose of this file is to ensure that git will create all my directories, even if they do not have files yet. As such i want to place an empty 0 byte .init file inside of each directory to ensure the "empty" directory is committed by git.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `!/*` after the initial exclude to allow directories and change init line to `!*.init`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create, e.g., `home/foo/.init` and have this file be put into Git's *index* (for more about the index, see below), you will need to tell Git *not* to cut off searches into the `home/*/` directories:

```
!home/*/
```

Then, as [Fady Adal noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63306691/1256452) (but I've adjusted slightly), you probably also want:

```
!**/.init
```

so that when Git searches `home/*/` it will find and de-ignore files named `.init`.  Note that this de-ignores *all* `.init` files; perhaps you want:

```
!home/**/.init
```

here so that you can ignore a file named, e.g., `nothome/foo/.init`.  (You might even ignore `home/**/*` while un-ignoring `home/**/*/` and `home/**/.init`.)

## Long: what's going on here?

I like to say that Git stores only files, not directories, and this is true—but the *reason* it's true has to do with the way Git builds new commits, which is, from Git's *index*.

#### Commits and the index

Each *commit* stores a full and complete copy of every file that Git knows about.  This full-and-complete copy, however, is stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen-for-all-time format in which duplicate files are automatically de-duplicated.  That way, the fact that your first commit has (say) a `README.md` file that hardly ever changes, means that every commit just *shares* that `README.md` file.  If it does change, the new commits begin sharing the new file.  If it changes back, new commits after that go back to sharing the original file.  So if there are only three *versions* of `README.md`, despite having 3 million commits, those 3 million commits all share the three *versions* of the file.

But note that these files are literally read-only.  You can't change them.  Not even *Git* can change them (for technical reasons having to do with hash IDs; this is true of all existing commits too).  They're not in a format that most of your computer programs can use, either.  That means that to *work on* the file, or even just to *look* at it, Git has to expand out the frozen-and-compressed, Git-only committed file, into an ordinary everyday form.

This means that when you pick some commit to work on it, Git has to *extract* all the files from that commit.  So there are already two copies of each file: the frozen one, in the Git-only compressed-and-de-duplicated form, and the useful one, in your work-tree.

Most version control systems (VCS-es) have this same pattern: there's a committed copy of each file, in some VCS-specific form, saved inside the VCS, and there's a plain-text / ordinary-format version that you work on.  Many VCSes stop here, with just the two active files (and one of them might be stored in some central repository, rather than on your computer; Git stores the VCS copy on your computer).

To make a *new* commit, then, the VCS obviously has to package up all of your work-tree (ordinary-format) files.  Some version control systems literally do this.  Most at least stick a cache in here to make this go faster, because doing things this way is painfully slow.  Git, however, uses a sneaky trick.

In Git, there's a *third* copy of each active file.  This third copy goes in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  Technically this one isn't usually a *copy* as Git stores it in the internal, compressed-and-de-duplicated form, so it's really just a reference to a blob-hash-ID.  This also means that it's ready to go into the *next* commit.

**What this means is that the index—or staging area, if you prefer that term—can be described as holding *the next commit you intend to make*.**  The index takes on an expanded role during conflicted merges, so this is not a complete description, but it's good enough for thinking about it.  When you use `git commit` to make a new commit, Git just packages up all the prepared, frozen-format, pre-de-duplicated files from the index.  But the index holds only *files*—files with long names, like `home/a/.init` for instance, but *files*, not directories.

Checking out some commit, to work on it, means extracting the files from that commit.  Git puts them—in their frozen format, but now change-able—into the index so that they're ready to make a *new* commit, and de-compresses them into ordinary format in your work-tree so that you can see and work on them.  Then, when you use `git add`, you are telling Git: *Make the index copy of some file match the work-tree copy of that file.*

- If there's already an index copy, the index copy gets booted out (it's probably safely in some commit though) and Git de-duplicates the work-tree copy into the appropriate compressed, frozen-format copy and puts *that* in the index instead.
- If there *wasn't* an index copy, now there is.  (It's also still de-duplicated: if you make a new file that has some old file's content, the old content from the old commit gets re-used.)

Either way, it's now ready to go into a new commit.

#### This is where `.gitignore` comes in

The `.gitignore` files are somewhat misnamed.  They do not literally make Git *ignore* a file.  A file's presence, or absence, in new commits you make is determined strictly by whether the file was in the index at the time you ran `git commit`.

What `.gitignore` does instead is two-fold.  First, when you use `git status`, Git will *complain* about files that exist in your work-tree, but are not in Git's index.  This complaint comes in the form of telling you that some file is *untracked*.  This is literally what untracked means: that there is a file in your work-tree, where you can see it and edit it and so on, that isn't in Git's index *right now*.  That's *all* it means, since you can put a file into Git's index (`git add`) or take one out (`git rm` or `git rm --cached`) at any time.  But because the index is the source of each *new* commit, it's important to know whether some file is in the index or not—which is why Git complains if it's not.

Sometimes, though, this complaint is just annoying: *Yes, I know this compiled object-code file is not in the index.  Don't tell me!  I **know** already and it's not important!*  So, to keep Git from complaining, you list the file in another file that probably should be called `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-untracked-files`.

But that's not the only thing that you get by listing the file in `.gitgnore`.  It not only shuts up `git status`, it also makes `git add` *not* actually add the file.  So `git add *` or `git add .` *won't* add the object-code file, or whatever.  So to keep Git from adding, you list the file in a file that perhaps should be called `.git-do-not-auto-add-these-files`.

Hence `.gitignore` might be called `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-untracked-files-and-do-not-automatically-add-them-either`.  But once those files *are* in the index, a `.gitignore` entry has no effect, so maybe it should be `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-untracked-files-and-do-not-automatically-add-them-either-but-if-they-are-in-the-index-go-ahead-and-commit-them`.  But that's just ridiculous, so `.gitignore` it is.

#### Scanning directories is slow

When you have a massive Git repository, with millions<sup>1</sup> of files in it, some of the things that Git normally does very quickly start really bogging down.  Even at just a few hundred thousand files, some things can be slow.  One of the slowest is scanning through a directory (or folder) to look for untracked files.<sup>2</sup>

By listing a *directory*, such as `home/a/`, in a `.gitignore` file, you give Git permission to take a shortcut.  Normally, Git would say to itself: *Ah, here is a directory `home/a`.  I must open it and read out every file in it, and see if those files are in the index or not, in order to decide whether these files are untracked and/or need to be added.*  But if the entire directory is to be ignored, Git can stop a little short: *Wait!  I see `home/a` is to be ignored!  I can skip it entirely!*  And so it goes on to `home/b/` instead of looking inside `home/a/`.

To make sure that Git *doesn't* skip a directory, you must make sure that it's not ignored.  This is where trailing slashes in the `.gitignore` entries come in.

---

<sup>1</sup>Most aren't even this big, but Microsoft are working on making Git perform with repositories of this size.

<sup>2</sup>The usual trick for these kinds of speed issues is to insert a cache.  The problem here is that untracked files are, by definition, not in the index.  Git's index does have an extension to do some untracked caching but this can never catch everything.

---

#### The `.gitignore` line format

The format of lines in `.gitignore` is:

- blank and comment lines are ignored;
- lines that start with `!` are negations;
- lines that *end* with `/` refer to directories; and
- the rest of the line names the file, complete with leading and/or embedded slashes.

A negation only makes sense to undo the effect of an earlier line.  In general, later lines override earlier lines, but there is that one big exception having to do with skipping entire directories.

A line that—after any `!` marking a negation—*starts* with a slash provides a *rooted* or *anchored* path.<sup>3</sup>  So `/home` for instance means just that—`/home`—and not something like `a/home`.  A line that *contains an embedded slash* is also rooted, so that `home/a` and `/home/a` both mean the same thing.

The final slash, if there, gets *removed* from the "is rooted/anchored" test.  That is, `home/` and `/home/` are different, because `home` is non-rooted/non-anchored but `/home` is rooted/anchored.

As Git scans through directories (folders) and subdirectories (sub-folders), it will try matching each *file or directory name* it finds at each level to all the non-rooted / non-anchored names.  Only those at the level of that particular `.gitignore` get matched against the rooted / anchored names, though.

A trailing slash in the pattern means *match only if this is a directory*.  So if `home/a` is a directory, it matches both `home/*` and `home/*/`; if `home/xyz` is a file, it matches only `home/*`, not `home/*/`.

Hence, if we want to ignore all *files* underneath `home`, we use:

```
home/*
```

to ignore them.  This has an embedded slash so it is rooted/anchored.  Unfortunately it gives Git permission to *skip* all subdirectories, so we must counter that with:

```
!home/*/
```

which has a trailing slash so that it applies only to directories.  It too is anchored.

---

<sup>3</sup>I'm borrowing the term *anchored* from regular expression descriptions here.  *Rooted* refers to the top level of the Git repository work-tree.  Both terms should convey the right idea; use whichever you like better.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
home/*      #exclude everything in the home directory and subdirectories
!home/*.py  #include python files immediately in the home directory
!**/*.init    #include .init files in all directories and subdirectories.
```